# how to handle long path name for pep8 compliance?

Tags: python, pep8

How would I handle long path name like below for pep8 compliance? Is 79 characters per line a must even if it becomes somewhat unreadable?

```
def setUp(self):
    self.patcher1 = patch('projectname.common.credential.CredentialCache.mymethodname')
```

Comment: Note that 79 is only *required* for code in the standard library. PEP 8 is explicitly more relaxed for other code: "Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length from 80 to 100 characters (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99 characters), provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Use a variable to store this

   ```
   def setUp(self):
       path = 'projectname.common.credential.CredentialCache.mymethodname'
       self.patcher1 = patch(path)
   ```
2. String concatenation:

   An assignment like `v = ("a" "b" "c")` gets converted into `v = "abc"`:

   ```
   def setUp(self):
       self.patcher1 = patch(
           "projectname.common.credential."
           "CredentialCache.mymethodname")
   ```
3. Tell pep8 that we don't use 80-column terminals anymore with --max-line-length=100 (or some sufficiently reasonable value). (Hat Tip @chepner below :) )

Comment: 3. Tell `pep8` that we don't use 80-column terminals anymore with `--max-line-length=100` (or some sufficiently reasonable value).

Comment: Why the double parentheses in `patch((` ? One set of parentheses works just as well.

Comment: @khelwood In this case, yes it would work, but it there are multiple such strings, we would need multiple parantheses. Will add a note to that effect.

Comment: I don't think multiple parentheses would ever be necessary; the comma separating them as multiple arguments would be sufficient to stop the interpreter from concatenating them.

Comment: @chepner You are right, just verified that in the shell; I incorrectly remembered that that didn't work.

Comment: @mu無 Thank you for suggesting different ways of handling the issue. #2 seems to be a simple and nice solution for now but #3 is really useful!

Answer (score 2):

The 79-character limit in PEP8 is based more on historical beliefs than in actual readability. All of PEP8 is a guideline, but this one is more frequently ignored than most of the recommendation. The `pep8` tool even has a specific option for changing the value of what is considered "too long".

```
pep8 --max-line-length 100 myscript.py
```

I frequently just disable the test altogether:

```
pep8 --ignore E501 myscript.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The 80 columns guideline is not only for the sake of people coding on 1980 barkley unix terminals, but it also guarantees some uniformity across projects. Thanks to it you can set the GUI of your IDE to your liking and be sure that it will be good for all the different projects.

Alas sometimes the best solution is to violate it, it is extremely rare case but it sure happens. And jusst for that reason you can tag that line with comment:`# noinspection PyPep8` so you could turn your code into:

```
def setUp(self):
    # noinspection PyPep8
    self.patcher1 = patch('projectname.common.credential.CredentialCache.mymethodname')
```

Which will allow you to follow the guidelines of pep8 all around, including the line limitations, and not have to worry about this false report. Sadly this directive isn't supported with all the checkers, but it is slowly getting there.

Comment: Have *some* limit is useful for uniformity; having that limit be 80 is artificially restrictive for most people (especially in Python, where the indentation requirement add some non-removable overhead to the line length).

Comment: @chepner if you are reaching that deep into indentation then your code has to undergo very serious refactoring. And the fact that you are hitting 80 columns mark is a good indication of that.

Comment: The user's example already shows the effect of indentation. A single method inside a single class already imposes a "penalty" of 2 levels of indentation that cannot be reasonably removed. This point was specifically addressed by Raymond Hettinger in his PyCon 2015 talk [Beyond PEP 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M).

Comment: @chepner this isn't effect of indentation, this is effect of ridiculously long string used as argument to a function which can be very easily broken down. As you may see indentation is the minority of the whole line, and yet you try to blame the world on it.
So you may want to come with some better examples that actually show where it's the indentation, not horrible code design, is the cause for crossing over 80 columns.

Comment: A class, that contains a method, which uses a loop that contains an if statement which uses a `logging.Logger` instance. Now we're up to 4 levels of indentation, and it's perfectly reasonable for a log message itself to take up a significant chunk of your 80-character limit. There's only so much room you could reclaim by using less than the recommended 4 spaces for indentation. Why should I be forced to break the string into two pieces just because it pushed the line length to, say, 85 characters?

Comment: @chepner so you don't have a real life example? Well then, lets stick to your imaginary one. In this I would move away the logic into either functions or class methods and the main function works only as facade which calles the functions with eventual conditioning. This way you wind up code that is no deeper than 2 levels of indentation at the start, which leaves more than plenty space in practice to do anything you want. Feel free to show me a real life example that proves me wrong.
And you can do anything you want, but don't be surprised when no one wants to work on your ugly code later on.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer variant with concatenation.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.patcher1 = patch(
        "projectname.common.credential."
        "CredentialCache.mymethodname")
```

Also concatenation braces are not required when calling a function.